# Grails Mongodb find doesn't work with dot notation, dynamic attributes

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have the following code in a Grails controller which returns the expected result:

```
def alm = SiteHistory.collection.find([
   "phoneNumber":"${params.phoneNumber}",
   "fields.P2Running":true])
   .limit(20).toArray()
```

However, I would like to modify the search based on input parameters.  The follow ing query returns no document when params.alarm == "P2Running"

```
def fieldsSelect = "fields."+params.alarm
def alm = SiteHistory.collection.find([
   "phoneNumber":"${params.phoneNumber}",
   fieldSelect:true])
   .limit(20).toArray()
```

I have also tried:

```
def fieldsSelect = "fields."+params.alarm
def alm = SiteHistory.collection.find([
   "phoneNumber":"${params.phoneNumber}",
   "${fieldSelect}":true])
   .limit(20).toArray()
```

which yields

```
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:134)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:142)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage._appendQuery(OutMessage.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:38)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:303)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:498)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._fill(DBCursor.java:558)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:596)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:584)
    at remote.SiteHistoryController$_closure2$$EO0HJb0Z.doCall(SiteHistoryController.groovy:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My domain object is

```
class SiteHistory {
    ObjectId id
    String phoneNumber
    Date receiveDate=null
    Map<String,Object> fields = [:]
    static mapWith = "mongo"
}
```

The string key in fields will not be known until the data is added.

A sample document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("513eaefe290b3700b8e2c966"),
    "phoneNumber" : "1234567890",
    "receiveDate" : "Wed Mar 06 2013 23:52:47 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    "fields" : {
            "P1Runtime" : 37.6,
            "P1Starts" : 23,
            "P1Running" : false,
            "P2Runtime" : 35.7,
            "P2Starts" : 25,
            "P2Running" : true,
            "WetWellLvl" : 10,
            "HighLvlAlarm" : false
    }
}
```

Any ideas why a string created from params doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried ${fieldSelect}:true or ${fieldSelect}.toString():true ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both.  The first results in a stacktrace shown above. The second returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works with Grails 2.0.1 and Mongodb 1.0.0.RC4:

```
def query = new BasicDBObject("phoneNumber", params.phoneNumber)
    .append("fields.${params.alarm}", true)

def alm = SiteHistory.collection.find(query).limit(20).toArray()
```

I did not try using a Criteria because I read somewhere that they did not work with mongodb objects.  However, I do have namedQueries that are working on this object. So I tried a criteria and IT WORKS! (NOTE: it works with Grails 2.2.1 and mongodb 1.2.0.)

Here is the code:

```
def c = SiteHistory.createCriteria()
def alm = c.list (max:20, offset:0) {
    eq ("phoneNumber", params.phoneNumber)
    eq ("fields.${params.alarm}", true)
}
```

There are other issues that I'm having with Grails 2.2.1 so I will not upgrade yet.